# How Can I Use A Python Variable In A SQL Query So That Parameters Are Processed?

Tags: python, sql, variables, parameters

This should be pretty basic; I am not sure what the error I am making is. I am attempting to query a database using a Python variable in the query and I am able to query successfully with this:

`locationIDSelectQuery = ('SELECT locationId FROM stateTemplate WHERE id = 1')
cursor.execute(locationIDSelectQuery)`

and unsuccessfully with this:

`stateTableRowId = 1
cursor.execute("SELECT locationId FROM stateTemplate WHERE id=?", stateTableRowId)`

When I try this in the latter it doesn't work either `(statetableRowID)`.

Same error message in both instances:
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 29, in 
    cursor.execute("SELECT locationId FROM stateTemplate WHERE id=?", (stateTableRowId))

ValueError: Could not process parameters

How can I use a Python variable in my SQL query?

Comment: You need the pass a tuple of parameters, I believe. So `(stateTableRowId,)` notice the comma (which is what makes it a tuple)

Answer (score 1):

try the following, replace `?` with `%s`

```
stateTableRowId = 1
cursor.execute("SELECT locationId FROM stateTemplate WHERE id=%s", stateTableRowId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined the recommendations of @zealous and @juanpa.arrivillaga to arrive at a working solution:`stateTableRowId = 1
cursor.execute("SELECT locationId FROM stateTemplate WHERE id=%s", (stateTableRowId,))`

My understanding is that it may be preferable for security reasons to use `?` instead of `%s`. I have yet to get that to work with the database to which I'm connecting.